# Recover Python Notebook Variable After VScode Kernel Crash

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was running some python code in an ipynb file in Vscode and got the following message: "The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done"

While running it was appending to a large python list, and I'm wondering if its possible to recover that list. The code was running for a few days so simply rerunning it will be difficult.

Comment: A RAM-only variable is nearly impossible to recover without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `%store` magic command and re-run your notebook one more time. This magic command stores the list and you can restore it without re-running your notebook ever again.

Here is how to use it assuming `big_list` is the big list you are tyring to store:

```
%store big_list
```

Now, you have stored your list (`big_list`). You can restore it by using the following command even after restarting your notebook kernel:

```
%store -r
```

More information can be found [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html)